# Error voting in Tezos

Tags: node, voting

I've created a node that runs well with these steeps :

```
git clone -b mainnet https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos.git    
cd tezos
git checkout mainnet            
git rev-parse HEAD    
cd
sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)
opam init --comp=4.06.1           (hace 2 preguntas, responder YES a las dos, y al final ->Updating ~/.profile.)
opam switch 4.06.1
opam update
eval $(opam env)
cd tezos
make build-deps
eval $(opam env)
make
./tezos-node identity generate    
./tezos-node config init
./tezos-node config update --rpc-addr=127.0.0.1:8732
```

The node runs good as a full node or private one. But when I try to vote I can't do it because tezos-client gives me a syntax error because it doesn't recognize the commands.

Comment: Please provide the exact command you are running and the error that is being displayed.